# TForm is hiding behind Main window

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl, tform, owlnext

I have a main Form created with OwlNext that calls a Dialog which is created in vcl.

```
MyOtherFormClass Form2=new Form2();
void MyMainForm::ShowForm2(void) {
    Form2->ShowDialog(this);
}
class MyOtherFormClass {
    [...]
    TForm *myForm;

  void ShowDialog(TWindow* parent){

    TForm* tf = new TForm((HWND)NULL);
    tf->ParentWindow=parent->Handle;

    myForm= new TForm(tf);
    myForm->Parent=tf->Parent;
    myForm->Caption = "Form2";
    myForm->Height = 950;
    myForm->Width = 1350;
    myForm->BorderIcons << biMinimize << biMaximize << biSystemMenu;
    myForm->BorderStyle = bsSizeable;
    myForm->Show();
}
}
```

Now I have both windows with a new taskbar-entry.
When I click the Main-WIndow there, it get in front of Form2.
But when I click Form2, it stays behind the Main.
Also, when Form2 makes an alert, closing the alert will focus Main instead of Form2.

```
MessageBox(NULL, "An Alert!", "!", MB_OKCANCEL)
```

Can you tell me what I did wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you creating 2 `TForm` objects? You only need 1.

`tf->Parent` is NULL since `tf->ParentWindow` is used (BTW, you can pass `parent->Handle` to the `TForm(HWND)` constructor), so `myForm` has no parent window assigned, just an Owner that you are not keeping track of.  Owner and Parent are two different things.  You probably want the `MainForm` to be the parent of the Form2 window.

As for your `MessageBox()` call, you are not giving it an owner window.  You need to do that so it knows which window to stay in front of, and more importantly which window to focus when it closes.

Try this instead:

```
MyOtherFormClass *Form2 = new MyOtherFormClass();

void MyMainForm::ShowForm2(void) {
    Form2->ShowDialog(this);
}

class MyOtherFormClass {
    //...
    TForm *myForm;

    void ShowDialog(TWindow* parent) {
        myForm = new TForm(parent->Handle);
        myForm->Caption = "Form2";
        myForm->Height = 950;
        myForm->Width = 1350;
        myForm->BorderIcons = TBorderIcons() << biMinimize << biMaximize << biSystemMenu;
        myForm->BorderStyle = bsSizeable;
        myForm->Show();
    }
};
```

```
MessageBox(myForm->Handle, "An Alert!", "!", MB_OKCANCEL);
```

Comment: mostly it works, but I guess the mainwindow being an mdi-window may be a problem... now the "child"-window is within the main window... I also tried parent->Parent->Handle however, now it's still within that window but above the tool-bar... is there any property to tell myForm to be not an MDI-Child? ^^

Comment: If you want `myForm` to be free-floating then do not assign any parent window at all.

Comment: Well, if I give (HWND)NULL as parameter, the Form stays behind the Main Form when I click on it in the task-bar...

Comment: Well, what do you want it to do? Either it is free-floating, or it is embedded.

Comment: Well, it isn't free floating like it should with NULL. In that case: I open Form2: Form 2 is in Front. Then I click in taskbar on Mainform, Main form is in Front. Then I click in taskbar on Form 2, Mainform stays in Front. Here I would expect Form 2 to get in front...

Comment: Just to clarify, I use the code you posted here now and Form2 does'nt loose front-position anymore, when I open a messagebox, but I can't switch between Main and Form2 on my taskbar. Form2 stays behind Main unless I minimize and restore Form2...

Comment: A bit late but you could use GetActiveWindow() instead of NULL.  That way, it will either be a child of the main form or the current active window.